# count of count of recurunces in an array using c++

Tags: c++

i am trying to get the total amounts of numbers occurunces , my main problem is that i messed up some where and i cant read numbers that are higher than 12 , as in my count wont see it other than that works perfectly  , doesnt matter if sorted on not array doesnt affect the program(for my random array example)

```
*** int Count(int r[], int n, int x) {
    int res = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <n; i++)
        if (x == r[i])
            res++;
    return res;
}



int main() {

    int count = 0;
    int r[12] = { 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8,13,13  };
    int n = sizeof(r) / sizeof(r[0]); 


    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {

            if (r[i] > r[j])
            {
                swap(r[i], r[j]);
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        if (Count(r, n, i) >= 2) {
            count++;
            cout << "number" << i << "-" << Count(r, n, i) << " Recurrences" << endl;
        }
    }
    cout << "count is " << count;

    return 0;

} ***
```

Comment: Did you try stepping through the code with a debugger?

Comment: i did  yeah i am afraid my knowledge isnt enough to help me understand my error , i cant track the problem

Comment: So the when you were stepping through the code you got exactly the results you expected? In that case what is the problem? Otherwise you would have gotten to a point where the code did something you did not expected.

Answer (score 1):

Try an easier and more optimized way using `map`:

```
int r[12] = { 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 13, 13 };
int n = sizeof(r) / sizeof(r[0]);
map<int, int> map;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    if (map.find(r[i]) != map.end())
    {
        map[r[i]]++;
    }
    else
    {
        map[r[i]] = 1;
    }
}

for (auto const& x: map)
{
    cout << x.first << ':' << x.second << std::endl;
}
```

output

```
1:2
2:1
3:1
4:1
5:1
6:2
7:1
8:1
13:2
```

Comment: how can i get the count of total occurances using this method , for example  1 apears 2 times ,  6 appears 2 times , 13 appears 2 times , and the count is 3

Comment: In ```for``` of ```map```, you can add conditions to calculate it

Comment: @jim 
int i=0;
for (auto const& x: map)
{
    if(x.second)>=2;
    i++;
}